# FatalThrowableError Call to a member function where() on null for laravel 5.5 API request

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel-5.5

Hi I am trying to build the API from laravel. I am using eloquent resources to manage API. I get `FatalThrowableError Call to a member function where() on null` when passing id that do not exist in database.

Routes :

```
 Route::resource('hotel', 'HotelController',['only'=>['index','show']]);
```

Resource :

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->hotel_id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'summary' => $this->summary,
        'description' => $this->description,
        'contactno' => $this->contactno,
        'address' => $this->address,
        'latitude' => $this->latitude,
        'longitude' => $this->longitude,
        'star' => $this->star,
        'image' => base_resource_url().$this->image,
        'facilities' => $this->facility,
      ];
  }
}
```

Controller :

```
public function show($id) 
{
    return new HotelResource(Hotel::find($id)->where(['suspend'=>1,'verify'=>1])->first());
}
```

When I pass the ID that is present in database I can get the json data but when I pass the ID that is not present in database in show($id) method of controller then I get `FatalThrowableError Call to a member function where() on null` how can I handle this exception in laravel to throw some readable json error response like :

`{error : not data found with accosiated ID}`

Comment: First find hotel, check if something found, then apply `where`. Or create a query `where id = ID and suspend = 1 and verify = 1`.

Comment: This would result in two query to execute. One to check and one to return data but I want in single query.

Comment: One query is `where id = ID and suspend = 1 and verify = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check that the record exists first. For example:

```
public function show($id) 
{
    if ($hotel = Hotel::find($id)) {
         // hotel exists
    }

    abort(404, 'Hotel does not exist');
}
```

**Update**

`Hotel::find($id)` will only return 1 or 0 records. Applying the where clauses followed by `first()` doesn't make sense.

```
// is this what you mean?
Hotel::where(['id' => $id, 'suspend' => 1, 'verify' => 1])->first()
```

**Update 2**

```
public function show($id) 
{
    if ($hotel = Hotel::where(['id' => $id, 'suspend' => 1, 'verify' => 1])->first()) {
        return new HotelResource($hotel);
    }

    abort(404, 'Hotel does not exist');;
}
```

Comment: Well your query doesn't make much sense. It's saying "Find the hotel that has id $id. Then take that hotel and search on the one result where suspend and verify equal 1. And then with that single result, take the first one."

Comment: I had already mentioned that I am trying to make rest api with laravel API resources in laravel 5.5.  Hope this make sense.

Comment: I use the API resource classes nearly everyday. The query still is wrong as it is.

Comment: Ok found that first() doesn't make sense there. But issue is not about that. Its about error mentioned in question

Comment: Yes, which I addressed in my answer already. You need to check that it exists before passing it to `HotelResource`.